# Windows 8 emulator not working

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

## Emulator not running

I am using windows phone sdk 8.0 but I am unable to run emulator in visual studio 2012, is there any case to run it,
 I checked my machine and its SLAT capable...

I tried using various links provided but IT would be great help if any ne give me a direct solution, I check the Hyper-v also not enabling in the windows turn on and off features.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you getting any error message when you run the emulator?

Comment: Please add more details. Only with this much information we cannot get much idea

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to enable in the BIOS:
Hardware-assisted virtualization.
Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).

or you don't have:
4 GB or more of RAM.
64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro edition or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wording of your question I'm guessing you have a problem with enabling Hyper-V. Even if your computer is SLAT capable, you still need to enable it along with DEP and hardware-assisted virtualization in the BIOS like Goran said. This procedure is slightly different for AMD and Intel computers. The full information is here in the "Enabling BIOS settings required by Hyper-V" section.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Also just to be sure you don't actually need 4gb of RAM :). I only have 3.

IF you have gone through this whole procedure, sometimes you will still get an error that you are not part of the local Hyper-V administrators group. Just click retry and enter the admin password and everything should be ok.

Comment: I checked my pc with some tool which says its SLAT capable, while enabling Hyper-V in BIOS i was not able to find anything related to DEP or anything else. I was trying to update it from control panel, so I didnt found anything in that, some link which says that you have to turn windows feature on for Hyper-V, alas its not in the list of that features. I downloaded some dll also to enable it, after which the manager was available in cntrol panel but didnt gave the expected response. please help thanks

Comment: I checked it again with the link you provided, i used coreinfo tool to check. Everything is fine but I am not able to enable Hyper-V in windows, because its not showing in the windows turn on and off feature. Please help me out...

Comment: You're saying you can't find the options in the BIOS? My friend had a similar problem and we found the only way is to use a virtual machine, install visual express and enable hyper-v in the VM. Here's how: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWANk_XaovqM&sa=X&ei=f00fUsXKMZPWsATIzIDYBw&ved=0CAcQqwQ